# Filtering dollar values with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I'm using mongodb and I want to select objects with AppraisedValueDisplay between 2 dollar values. I have tried filtering by :

```
{AppraisedValueDisplay: {$gt: 5000,$lt: 50000}}
```

This gives no results
:
I then realized that (screenshot), The value is saved in a string format like:

```
$35,000
```

How do I filter by dollar values in mongodb?

Comment: the easiest way to handle such thing would be to use `aggregation` and have a `$project` on `AppraisedValueDisplay` with [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) and remove the `$` symbol, then simply run your query over that value.

Comment: You should be storing the values as either integers or decimals and add the dollar signs in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to preface this by saying that storing numeric values in your database formatted for presentation as strings is a bad idea, which you no doubt already know.

With that out of the way, here is the aggreagation you're looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "AppraisedValueDisplay": {
        $replaceAll: {
          input: "$AppraisedValueDisplay",
          find: {
            $literal: "$"
          },
          replacement: ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "AppraisedValueDisplay": {
        "$toInt": {
          $replaceAll: {
            input: "$AppraisedValueDisplay",
            find: ",",
            replacement: ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      AppraisedValueDisplay: {
        $gt: 30000,
        $lt: 40000
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The idea is to replace the `$` and `,` with empty strings and then cast the resulting strings to integers. From that point, it's just a simple matter of matching the numeric values.
Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/YU65M-q1QCM

Answer (score 1):

You should consider saving data in a format that you usually need to retrive as other users said in the comments.
But for this specific usecase you can use aggregate query to filter the results.

First convert the value into double and then match, I tested this query with mongodb version 4.0.23

```
db.tempCol.aggregate([
    {
        '$addFields':{
            'signRemoved': {
                '$reduce': {
                    'input': { '$split': [ '$AppraisedValueDisplay', { $literal: '$' } ] },
                    'initialValue': '',
                    'in': {
                        '$concat': [
                            '$$value',
                            {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$$value', '']}, '', ', ']}, 
                            '$$this'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        '$addFields':{
            'commaRemoved': {
                '$reduce': {
                    'input': { '$split': [ '$signRemoved', ',' ] },
                    'initialValue': '',
                    'in': {
                        '$concat': [
                            '$$value',
                            {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$$value', '']}, '', '']}, 
                            '$$this'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        '$addFields':{
            matchPrice: { '$toDouble': '$commaRemoved' }
        }
    },
    {
        '$match':{
            matchPrice: { '$gt': 5000, '$lt': 50000}
        }
    },
])
```