# MongoDb: Update value of collection field to remove non-numeric characters

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I'm using mongodb and I want to select objects with AppraisedValueDisplay between 2 dollar values. I have tried filtering by :

```
{AppraisedValueDisplay: {$gt: 5000,$lt: 50000}}
```

This gives no results
:
I then realized that (screenshot), The value is saved in a string format like:

```
$35,000
```

I was shown how to do this with [Filtering dollar values with mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66343749/filtering-dollar-values-with-mongodb) . With the aggregations listed, I am getting the right answer, but the original field is unchanged. How do change the field value in the original collection from

```
AppraisedValueDisplay : $35,000
```

to:

```
AppraisedValueDisplay : 35000
```

I want to explore the data in mongo-compass and I think this would simplify things.

Edit:

The following appears to work

> db.mycoll.find({AppraisedValueDisplay: {$exists: true}, $where: "this.AppraisedValueDisplay.length >0"}).forEach(function(obj){ myString = (obj.AppraisedValueDisplay); myString = myString.replace(/\D/g,''); obj.AppraisedValueDisplay = myString;       db.mycoll.save(obj);   })

Comment: You should write a JS script and load it in mongo shell, check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that option ..

Comment: I guess it's capable to found the solution via `js` code, do you have a `node,js` installed on your machine? In that case, I am capable to could write a personal script for you. But mongo shell is also an option. (But some functional is unavailable in native driver I guess)

Comment: @user1592380 Glad to help.